# Android: Firebase Crashlytics SDK not finding fatal exceptions after restart

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-beta

I am trying to implement crashlytics into the application i am working on, i followed the steps that are displayed in firebase docs. Application launches with no problem, i've added a button in the activity that is just for throwing a `RuntimeException` error in order to test `Crashlytics`. Everytime the app restarts after crash, i get this log warning:

```
02-19 09:58:50.691 10165 10207 W FirebaseCrashlytics: No minidump data found for session 5E4D4D0A007B-0001-26EA-D232ACE5317A
```

This is the result i get when i enable the DEBUG logging in `ADB`:

```
2020-02-19 09:50:48.561 9505-9505/? D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Reading cached settings...
2020-02-19 09:50:48.566 9505-9505/? D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Loaded cached settings: {"settings_version":3,"cache_duration":86400,"features":{"collect_logged_exceptions":true,"collect_reports":true,"collect_analytics":false},"app":{"status":"activated","update_required":true,"report_upload_variant":1},"fabric":{"org_id":"5e31a20ead709eecca000038","bundle_id":"com.??????"},"expires_at":1582126332033}
2020-02-19 09:50:48.566 9505-9505/? D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Returning cached settings.
2020-02-19 09:50:48.567 9505-9505/? D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Mapping file id is: 00000000000000000000000000000000
2020-02-19 09:50:48.567 9505-9505/? I/FirebaseCrashlytics: Initializing Crashlytics 17.0.0-beta01
2020-02-19 09:50:48.568 9505-9505/? D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Installer package name is: null
2020-02-19 09:50:48.578 9505-9505/? D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Exception handling initialization successful
2020-02-19 09:50:48.587 9505-9545/? D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Found matching FID, using Crashlytics IID: 776c46821c4d4cc39f1e7e831b0dfe00
2020-02-19 09:50:48.590 9505-9545/? D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Opening a new session with ID 5E4D4B480242-0001-2521-D232ACE5317A
2020-02-19 09:50:48.601 9505-9546/? D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Server says an update is required - forcing a full App update.
2020-02-19 09:50:48.619 9505-9545/? D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Initialization marker file created.
2020-02-19 09:50:48.628 9505-9545/? D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Registered Firebase Analytics event listener for breadcrumbs: true
2020-02-19 09:50:48.629 9505-9545/? W/FirebaseCrashlytics: No minidump data found for session 5E4D4B3D02C2-0001-24A1-D232ACE5317A
2020-02-19 09:50:48.629 9505-9545/? D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Finalizing previously open sessions.
2020-02-19 09:50:48.635 9505-9546/? D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Sending app info to https://api.crashlytics.com/spi/v1/platforms/android/apps/com.?????? // private
2020-02-19 09:50:48.638 9505-9545/? D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Closing open sessions.
2020-02-19 09:50:48.638 9505-9545/? D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Closing session: 5E4D4B3D02C2-0001-24A1-D232ACE5317A
2020-02-19 09:50:48.638 9505-9545/? D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Collecting session parts for ID 5E4D4B3D02C2-0001-24A1-D232ACE5317A
2020-02-19 09:50:48.640 9505-9545/? D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Session 5E4D4B3D02C2-0001-24A1-D232ACE5317A has fatal exception: false
2020-02-19 09:50:48.641 9505-9545/? D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Session 5E4D4B3D02C2-0001-24A1-D232ACE5317A has non-fatal exceptions: false
2020-02-19 09:50:48.641 9505-9545/? D/FirebaseCrashlytics: No events present for session ID 5E4D4B3D02C2-0001-24A1-D232ACE5317A
2020-02-19 09:50:48.641 9505-9545/? D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Removing session part files for ID 5E4D4B3D02C2-0001-24A1-D232ACE5317A
2020-02-19 09:50:48.643 9505-9545/? D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Closed all previously open sessions
2020-02-19 09:50:48.645 9505-9545/? D/FirebaseCrashlytics: No reports are available.
2020-02-19 09:50:48.647 9505-9545/? D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Initialization marker file removed:
```

I've also tried to use the `Fabric Crashlytics` library but i still get the same error. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @AtefFarouk no, my suspicion is that there is some background thread that is overriding the exception callback from firebase.. unfortunately the background thread is managed by a private library in which i have no access to

Comment: @Oscar.I tried empty clean project without any private library, and same results.  which could be related to firebase backend console

Comment: @AtefFarouk your issue might be different than mine.. in my case was that `CrashLytics` is not able to find the error dump. The private library we use captures logs which are sent to our server, which is why the library i use is the cause